# Surface tension factor 2

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

[image]

Can anyone please explain what is meant by this illustration when deriving the formula for the force of surface tension which is $2 L \sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the tension? Where does exactly the factor $2$ come from? Of course, I have read a thousand times that we have to take into consideration the two sides of the sliding blade, but I don't seem to understand how the blade is put relative to the liquid, what two sides, which surface gets bigger? I'm really confused and would be happy to get a detailed and illustrative answer!

Comment: can you please explain what is happening in the diagram? not everyone may already know the context

Comment: possible duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/212853/

Comment: Exactly, i don't understand what it means either, but it's the illustration put in all derivations for the force of the surface tension, it is in the context of surface tension

Comment: I just checked the link, it is similar to my question, however, there hasn't been any satisfactory answer...

Comment: Surface tension is 1. the energy of the surface molecules per unit area 2. the force per unit length exerted on either side of a line floating on a liquid's surface. From 1, when the film is stretched, area of the film increases by twice $dxL$, for the front and back sides. The energy increase is $\sigma (2 dx L)$, the force generated is $E/dx$